# Blazor WASM - Errors on application after publishing ( due to cache i think)

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

After publishing website occurs some strange errors every time.

- Unknown error occurred while trying to verify integrity.
- service-worker.js:22 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch  at service-worker.js:22.
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]

When i open the web application on browser's icongito mode everything is ok, so i think the problems becomes from cache.

Also it occurs mainly on Chrome. On firefox is ok after first Ctrl + f5 refresh.

What can cause this strange behaviour, and what can be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing PWA(Progressive web application) the behaviour stopped to exists. The error occured from Offline cache on browser (Cache - Cache Storage - offline-cache). maybe in .NET 6 release will be better perforance.